# Concat with glue / join using Mustache JS

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm trying to display an array of items with Mustache, and I'd like to show them with a comma separator.

Here is my object :

```
{"items": [
    {"display": "Item 1"},
    {"display": "Item 2"},
    {"display": "Item 3"},
    {"display": "Item 4"}
]}
```

And here's my Mustache JS template :

```
{{#items}}{{display}}, {{/items}}
```

Unfortunately, this will render as :

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4,
```

I'd like to remove the last ", ", since it seems odd visually.

I tried with functions, but I got the "{{items}}" text, not the array `items`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I posted a similar question with my own proposed answer. [See this posting for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287138/dynamic-tables-with-mustache-using-dynamic-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i know 2 ways of solve this, first is to program your own iterator helper (and this is the best solution), and the sencond, is to delete manually (with DOM Handling) the trailing coma.

just find the text with your javascript (`$("selector").html()`), and slice it.

```
var html = jQuery("selector").html();
html = html.slice(0, html.length-1);
```

that way you cut the last character.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a Mustache function.  These are defined in your template like any other section, then run on the content they're wrapped around.  For your case it would look something like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"display": "Item 1"},
    {"display": "Item 2"},
    {"display": "Item 3"},
    {"display": "Item 4"}
  ],
  "trim": function () {
    return function (text, render) {
      return render(text).replace(/(,\s*$)/g, ''); // trim trailing comma and whitespace 
    }
  }
}
```

Then your Mustache markup will look like this:

```
{{#trim}}{{#items}}{{display}}, {{/items}}{{/trim}}
```

And your output will be what you're after:

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4
```

Check it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxsszj6z/).